# Merge all child nodes of respective parent under first parent, if parent node value matches

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi My Input is something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <Claim>
            <Mileage>9837</Mileage>
            <DamagePosition>
               <DamageSeqNumber>3</DamageSeqNumber>
               <DamageCode>2727004</DamageCode>
               <PartPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>1</SeqNumber>
                  <PartNumber>A2035400253</PartNumber>
               </PartPosition>
            </DamagePosition>
            <DamagePosition>
               <DamageSeqNumber>1</DamageSeqNumber>
               <DamageCode>2727004</DamageCode>
               <PartPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>3</SeqNumber>
                  <PartNumber>A1409910055</PartNumber>
               </PartPosition>
            </DamagePosition>
            <DamagePosition>
               <DamageSeqNumber>8</DamageSeqNumber>
               <DamageCode>2727004</DamageCode>
               <OperationPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>8</SeqNumber>
                  <Opcode>02-2710-01</Opcode>
               </OperationPosition>
            </DamagePosition>
            <DamagePosition>
               <DamageSeqNumber>4</DamageSeqNumber>
               <DamageCode>3221136</DamageCode>
               <PartPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>4</SeqNumber>
                  <PartNumber>A2033202889</PartNumber>
               </PartPosition>
            </DamagePosition>
         </Claim>
```

and desired output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <Claim>
            <Mileage>9837</Mileage>
            <DamagePosition>
               <DamageSeqNumber>3</DamageSeqNumber>
               <DamageCode>2727004</DamageCode>
               <OperationPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>8</SeqNumber>
                  <Opcode>02-2710-01</Opcode>
               </OperationPosition>
               <PartPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>1</SeqNumber>
                  <PartNumber>A2035400253</PartNumber>
               </PartPosition>
               <PartPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>3</SeqNumber>
                  <PartNumber>A1409910055</PartNumber>
               </PartPosition>
               <OperationPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>8</SeqNumber>
                  <Opcode>02-2710-01</Opcode>
               </OperationPosition>
            </DamagePosition>
            <DamagePosition>
               <DamageSeqNumber>4</DamageSeqNumber>
               <DamageCode>3221136</DamageCode>
               <PartPosition>
                  <SeqNumber>4</SeqNumber>
                  <PartNumber>A2033202889</PartNumber>
               </PartPosition>
            </DamagePosition>
         </Claim>
```

I tried following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kuserID" match="DamagePosition"  use="DamageCode"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
         <xsl:sort select="DamageCode" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match=
 "DamagePosition|DamageCode
 |PartPosition"/>
 <xsl:template match=
  "DamagePosition
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kuserID', DamageCode)[1])
     ]">
  <DamagePosition>
   <xsl:copy-of select="DamageCode"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('kuserID',DamageCode)" />
  </DamagePosition>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="DamagePosition" mode="copy">
  <PartPosition>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </PartPosition>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it is giving me ouput like below, Though it is able to group child elements having same DamageCode, but not giving  the desired ouput, it is not copying all tags under part position, only seqNumber is visible in output . Also Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for all the help.

```
<Claim>
   <Mileage>9837</Mileage>
   <DamagePosition>
      <DamageCode>2727004</DamageCode>
      <PartPosition>
         <DamageSeqNumber>3</DamageSeqNumber>
      </PartPosition>
      <PartPosition>
         <DamageSeqNumber>1</DamageSeqNumber>
      </PartPosition>
      <PartPosition>
         <DamageSeqNumber>8</DamageSeqNumber>
         <OperationPosition>
            <SeqNumber>8</SeqNumber>
            <Opcode>02-2710-01</Opcode>
         </OperationPosition>
      </PartPosition>
   </DamagePosition>
   <DamagePosition>
      <DamageCode>3221136</DamageCode>
      <PartPosition>
         <DamageSeqNumber>4</DamageSeqNumber>
      </PartPosition>
   </DamagePosition>
</Claim>
```

Comment: I have closed your other two questions. In the future, please do not post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a template in your XSLT that ignores `PartPosition`

```
<xsl:template match="DamagePosition|DamageCode|PartPosition"/>
```

Therefore, when you do `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in your `copy` template, because you are positioned on a `DamagePosition` at this point, the above template will match the child `PartPosition` and simply ignore it.

Perhaps you should be ignoring `DamageSeqNumber` instead of `PartPosition` at this point?

Also, you probably don't really need the `copy` template at all. Instead, change the call to it, to simply get all the child elements of the key, and then let the identity template take care of it.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('kuserID',DamageCode)/*" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kuserID" match="DamagePosition"  use="DamageCode"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
         <xsl:sort select="DamageCode" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="DamagePosition|DamageCode|DamageSeqNumber"/>

 <xsl:template match="DamagePosition[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kuserID', DamageCode)[1])]">
  <DamagePosition>
   <xsl:copy-of select="DamageCode"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="DamageSeqNumber"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kuserID',DamageCode)/*" />
  </DamagePosition>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This doesn't quite give the output you show in your question, because you show two `OperationPosition` elements in your output, although there is only one in your input.

EDIT: If you wanted `OperationPosition` elements before `PartPosition` elements, you could replace the existing `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('kuserID',DamageCode)/*" />` with these two lines instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('kuserID',DamageCode)/OperationPosition" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('kuserID',DamageCode)/*[not(self::OperationPosition)]" />
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Tim, yes you are right about OpertaionPosition, actually this element in output was intended to be moved up and positioned below DamageCode only, I  pasted the output wrong, this output should have only one such element which is moved up. Can you please guide me on how to move this element up to the desired level. Thanks for the earlier help.

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how you can do this.